# Programmatically access image assets

Tags: ios, objective-c

My image assets catalog has a folder named "Nature" with hundreds of image files inside.

I would like to get an array of image file names under the "Nature" directory in my image assets. I will then choose a random image name from this array and display it with `[UIImage imageNamed:@"..."]`. I am stuck on how to get an array of image names under the 'IncludedStudyImages' directory. I cannot even find anything in the documentation on how to interact with my image assets programmatically (other than displaying them).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9):

this may be late but this might helps others

**you can not directly access all the file from assets as its compiled to .car**

alternative to access the all files from the assets is to create the .plist file with the all images that assets contains and plist file can be easily accessible. following are the steps to achieve this

**Step 1:** add script in Build Phases -> Run Script
[image]

```
echo "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>" >  ${SRCROOT}/${PROJECT_NAME}/files.plist;
## Chnage Assets.xcassets if not using default one
find ${SRCROOT}/${PROJECT_NAME}/Assets.xcassets -type f -not -iname "*@*" -name "*.png"  -exec basename {} \; | while read line; do echo \<key\>$line\</key\>\<string\>$line\</string\>; done >> ${SRCROOT}/${PROJECT_NAME}/files.plist;
echo "</dict></plist>" >>  ${SRCROOT}/${PROJECT_NAME}/files.plist;
```

> this script generate **files.plist** in project directory with all
>   images in assets file add this file to project

**Step2:** Accessing plist file

```
NSURL *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"files" withExtension:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *allXCAssetsImages = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filepath.path];
```

Answer (score 2):

I know there are 2 ways to get an array of image files.

---

**In assets use the same prefix for all your images and append an incrementing number**:
[image: Image names with incrementing number]
then you can:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bg_button%d", i]];
    NSLog(@"%@", image);
}
```

---

**Create folder references rather than image assets**

[image: When importing images choose create folder references]
[image: Images in folder]

So we can get an array of image files using this snippet:

```
NSString *directory = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Intro"];
NSArray *intros = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:directory];
NSLog(@"%@", intros);
```

---

Hope this did help you!

Answer (score 0):

I've searched this problem and get the conclusion that you could not access the `IncludedStudyImages` directory directly. Check these:

[Access Asset Catalog pathForResource](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18968352/1548523)
[Can I get a NSURL from an XCAssets bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21769092/1548523)

Another way work around is that you could predefine the file name according to some order. For example names like "image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png". And using this way you could do the selecting a random image feature.