# Get path of a file in a data set located in Assets.xcassets

Tags: swift, swift3, bundle

I have a data set of audio files in my `Assets.xcassets`:

[image: Assets.xcassets]

I'm trying to get the path of one of those audio files like this:

```
let path: String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "acoustic_grand_piano/A4", ofType: "f32")!
```

But I get a `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`. I tried to look on the internet but I don't find anything on Data Sets.

How can I get the content of one of these files?

Thanks!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39891180/1457385

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

- Manually put your files into a folder, named anything you want.
- Append ".bundle" to the folder to create a bundle. You'll get a warning, accept it. Congrats, you've just created your first bundle! :-)
- Manually drag that folder into your app.
- Get at your files by using the following code....

  ```
   public func returnFile(_ named:String) -> String {
       let path: String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "myAudioFiles", ofType: "bundle")! + "/" + name + ".f32"        
       do {
           return try String(contentsOfFile: path)
       }
       catch let error as NSError {
           return error.description
       }
   }
  ```

Now, my files are text files of CIKernel code. Since your's are audio files you may need to change the String return to something else.

EDIT:

In my case I'm using a framework, as I wish to share these files/images with extensions and other apps. If you are working in such a set up, here's the unaltered code:

```
public func returnFile(_ resource:String, _ fileName:String, _ fileType:String) -> String {
    let identifier = "com.companyname.appname" // replace with framework bundle identifier
    let fileBundle = Bundle.init(identifier: identifier)
    let filePath = (fileBundle?.path(forResource: resource, ofType: "bundle"))! + "/" + fileName + "." + fileType
    do {
        return try String(contentsOfFile: filePath)
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        return error.description
    }
}
```