# Use Images in a swift framework

Tags: swift, frameworks

I need a picture to appeare in a framework. The only way i found needed that i know the name of the app it is in. Is there another way to get assets into your framework?
(For getting this posted:

- my background search didnt help)

Comment: Why can't you use the name of your framework? Details matter. Like an app, a framework has a bundle name. Use that. If it's a third party framework, post more details.

Comment: 1. I could use the name of the framework but not the apps name it I will be nested in, and that was the only way I found.

Comment: 2. It would be nice to get an xcasset for the dark mode pictures (but not needed)

Answer (score 0):

Almost 5 years ago I posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41129204/get-path-of-a-file-in-a-data-set-located-in-assets-xcassets/41129688#41129688). It contains two pieces of code to pull out an asset from a Framework's bundle. The key piece of code is this:

```
public func returnFile(_ resource:String, _ fileName:String, _ fileType:String) -> String {
    let identifier = "com.companyname.appname" // replace with framework bundle identifier
    let fileBundle = Bundle.init(identifier: identifier)
    let filePath = (fileBundle?.path(forResource: resource, ofType: "bundle"))! + "/" + fileName + "." + fileType
do {
    return try String(contentsOfFile: filePath)
}
catch let error as NSError {
    return error.description
}
```

So what if your framework, which needs to know two things (app bundle and light/dark mode) tweaked this code? Move `identifier` out to be accessible to the app and not local to this function. Then create either a new variable (I think this is the best way) or a new function to work with the correct set of assets based on light or dark mode.

Now your apps can `import` your framework, and set things up in it's consumers appropriately. (I haven't tried this, but in theory I think it should work.)

Answer (score 0):

- Create a folder "Resources". Drag and drop the image in this folder
- create a class "ImageLoader" in a separate .swift file.

  ```
  import Foundation
  import UIKit

  public class ImageLoader {
  // Function to load an image from the framework bundle
     public static func loadImage() -> UIImage {
     // Get the bundle where the ImageLoader class resides
       let frameworkBundle = Bundle(for: ImageLoader.self)
       // Print the bundle for debugging purposes


       // Try to retrieve the URL of the image resource named "image.png" from the bundle
       guard let imageUrl = frameworkBundle.url(forResource: "image", withExtension: "png"),
         // Try to load the image data from the retrieved URL
         let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: imageUrl),
         // Try to create a UIImage from the loaded image data
         let image = UIImage(data: imageData) else {
       // If any of the above steps fail, use a default system image "chevron.right"
       let img = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.right")!
       return img
   }

   // Return the loaded image
   return image
     }
   }
  ```
- Make sure that the Resources folder and ImageLoader.swift file should be inside the same bundle.
- call the image in view file using the below code

  ```
  VStack {
       Text("Image imported")
       Image(uiImage: ImageLoader.loadImage())
           .resizable()
   }
  ```