# How to access Image Assets like an array in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, ios10

In my app I'm allowing the user the change some of the UI elements based on color. So, I have three versions of an image which can be used for a button and I'd like to select the image programmatically:

```
PSEUDO CODE
"image0", "image1", "image3"
var userChoice:integer

myButton.setImage("myImage"+userChoice , .normal)
```

I've seen this solution in SO:
[Programmatically access image assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30584992/programmatically-access-image-assets)

What would be the Swift equivalent code?

Right now I'm using image literal:

```
self.But_Settings.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "settingswhite"), for: UIControlState.normal)
```

but of course Xcode changes this part "#imageLiteral(resourceName: "settingswhite")" to an icon which cannot be edited.

Comment: Do you think this would help? : But_Settings.setImage(UIImage(named: "play.png"), for: UIControlState.normal). Here you are using name of the asset.

Comment: @VandanPatel - Yes, that does help. I wish you had given it as an answer so I could credit you. Nevertheless, thanks.

Comment: I just did that. lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then don't use image literal. Image literals are just that - a hard value in code that you can't change during run time. Load an image dynamically from your bundle:

```
if let image = UIImage(named: "myImage" + userChoice) {
    self.But_Settings.setImage(image, for: .normal)
}
```

Comment: Yes! and DUH! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you think this would help? : But_Settings.setImage(UIImage(named: "play.png"), for: UIControlState.normal). Here you are using name of the asset

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a limited number of choices it sounds like a good place for an enum.

```
enum ImageChoice: Int {
case zero = 0, one, two

var image: UIImage {
 switch self {
  case .zero:
   return // Some Image, can use the icon image xcode provides now
  case .one:
   return //another image
  case .two:
   return //another image
  }
 }
}
```

Then you can easily get the correct image by initializing the enum by using an Int value.

```
guard let userChoice = ImageChoice(rawValue: someInt) else { return //Default Image }
let image = userChoice.image
```