# Retrieving filenames from assets into an array

Tags: ios

Wondering if there is an updated example of how to retrieve the file names from the assets folder and store into an array?

Comment: Likely duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22520883/can-i-access-an-xcassets-directory-on-the-filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "assets folder" in the built app. At build time, asset catalogs are *compiled* into a *.car* file. Thus the running app has no access to the individual images in the catalog except through the usual `UIImage(named:)` and similar.

You could probably write a build script to parse the assets catalog at *build* time and write something into your app bundle that you could load in the running app.

However, the fact that you even want to get this information is itself a Bad Smell (antipattern). You should probably ask a question about what you *really* want to do. For example, if your goal is provide your app with a folder full of images that you can enumerate at runtime, you would use a folder reference, not the asset catalog.